# Problems in the Ramanujan Class Invariant $G_n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory

In page 290 of his second notebook , Srinivas Ramanujan defines 2 functions $G_n$ and $g_n$. And then proceeds to give a table of $G_n$. 
[image]

But looking at the papers of Bruce C. Berndt, Heng Huat Chan, and LiangCheng Zhang -(http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/toronto.pdf). The Values of $G_n$ of several n differ from Ramanujan's Table. Then what is the relation between these two values?

Comment: Some info in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ramanujang-andG-Functions.html might address your question.

Comment: Don't use all caps, pls. (That is equivalent to shouting, and is considered rude in this forum.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us define Ramanujan function $\chi(q)$ by $$\chi(q) = (1 + q)(1 + q^{3})(1 + q^{5})\cdots = (-q;q^{2})_{\infty}$$ then the definition of $G'_{n}$ given in the above image in question is $$G_{n}^{'-1/24} = 2^{-1/4}e^{\pi n/24}\chi(e^{-\pi n})$$ or what is the same as $$G'_{n} = 2^{6}e^{-\pi n}\chi^{-24}(e^{-\pi n})$$

But in Berndt's book as well as any standard reference (and in particular Ramanujan's classic paper "Modular Equations and Approximations to $\pi$") the definition of $G_{n}$ is given by $$G_{n} = 2^{-1/4}e^{\pi\sqrt{n}/24}\chi(e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}})$$

The relation between now accepted definition of $G_{n}$ and old $G'_{n}$ (in this image) is clearly seen to be $$G_{n^{2}} = G_{n}^{'-1/24}$$

Similar is the case for definition of $g_{n}$.

Comment: in your blog [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.in/2012/03/modular-equations-and-approximations-to-pi-part-1.html#.UlEUCNKzczT) you give an approximation for pi using these ie. $\pi=\frac{24}{\sqrt(n)}log(2^{0.25}G_n)$ so can you give that approximation for the $G_n$

Comment: Shivam, I can't understand your comment properly. In my blog I have given some values of $G_{n}$ as well as the approximations to $\pi$ arising out of these values of $G_{n}$. What approximations do you need? Also it is better if you can discuss these matters related to my blog using blog comments. In math.stackexchange we should discuss only those things which are relevant to one question.

Comment: I need approximation for $G'_n$

Comment: That you can calculate from the relation between $G_{n}$ and $G'_{n}$ I have given in the answer. If you need values in decimals use calculator and if you need in symbolic form (consisting of square/cube roots etc) then you need to do calculations manually.